# SQL Server INSERT statements

Tags: sql-server

This is my INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Exercise 2 (Exercise, [Calories Burned])
VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```

This is the error message that I receive:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid table name... you need to put brackets around it if there is a a space. Example: [Exercise 2]

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you really have a table called [Exercise 2] is it perhaps a Exercise_2 or Exercise2

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work... what error are you receiving?

Comment: if i put brackets around the Exercise 2 it comes up with this error:

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Exercise 2'.

Comment: Yes that means that your table name is not Exercise 2. Please check and see what your actual table name is. Here is another link that explains your server may not even allow you a space in the table name: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign

Comment: Do you need to also put a schema in front of it (something other than dbo) find your table in the object explorer, right click, Script Table / As Insert / To New Query window. That will generate the syntax for you. Finally, NEVER EVER say _doesn't work_. Explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO [Exercise 2] (Exercise, [Calories Burned]) VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```